# Random Image Upload Issues (backend)

Tags: magento-1.9, error, backend, image-upload

I've been trying to track down this issue for a bit now for a client, but because of it not showing up all the time, it's been tough. Essentially when an image is being uploaded, it's says "Uploading...", but gets stuck there & doesn't proceed with finishing the upload process.

It's never done this for me, but for my client, it's both been successful & failed in IE/Firefox/Chrome/Safari on different computers on both PC/MC platforms on multiple different internet connections (at home & office).

I tried simulating heavier backend usage (was logged-in in multiple browsers & attempted to do multiple backend functions while an image upload was taking place & it uploaded fine). I also looked at the server usage logs & at all of the times they were having issues, there were no traffic spikes. They also have decently high speed internet. So I think it's safe to say we can rule out these things.

Not sure what else to check. Any ideas?

They're on Magento 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You are trying as an end-user, try as a developer. Check the browser developer console for errors when uploading, check how far it goes in the upload function when it gets stuck, check the permissions of the file you are trying to upload, try uploading same file again and again and see it that works or not.